# How to active ActiveClass when the page is from a submenu using Blazor + Tailwind?

Tags: c#, css, .net, blazor, tailwind-css

I had a menu created with Blazor and some items of menu has a submenu with items. I need set a background when the current page is relationated with the main menu item.

For example, I have this items in Menu:

```
Home
About
Blog
   Article 1
   Article 2
Contact
```

If the current page is Home, the Home menu should be with the backgorund blue, and so on.

But if the Article 1 or Article 2 was the current page, the Blog item should be with the background blue.

I'm using a NavLink componente to create a menu items

```
<NavLink ActiveClass="custom-nav-menu-link-active" Match="NavLinkMatch.All" href="@menuItem.HrefValue">Blog</NavLink>
```

And to create the submenu and sub items, I'm using a ul tag with one foreach simple

```
<ul id="submenu">
    @foreach (var subItem in menuItem.Items)
    {
        <li>
            <NavLink href="@subItem.HrefValue" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                Article 1
                @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(subItem.ArrowDropdownUrl))
                {
                    <img src="@subItem.ArrowDropdownUrl" alt="Dropdown Icon" class="iconmenuwithicon" />
                }
            </NavLink>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

For now when I click in Blog item the ActiveClass working very well, but when I click in some sub item not any menu item receive the backgorund blue, because the NavLink set the ActiveClass only in the item that had the URL correspondence.

Exists a way to implement the functionality that I nedd?

Comment: use `NavLinkMatch.Prefix` and make sure your submenus are an extension of the parent menu's url.
https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web/Routing/NavLink.cs,edbefa06b470c54e,references

Comment: I'm not using a extension of url. I need use the personal url, for example: /blog , /article1 , /article2

And I tryed use the Prefix, but don't working.